# AngularJs input[type=file] bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, file-upload, angular-resource

I want to handle file uploads using angularjs. I have settled up a model, view, controller and service that is included in the controller:

```
#Model
window.App.factory 'RepositoryItem', (railsResourceFactory) ->
  railsResourceFactory
    url: '/api/repository_items/{{_id && _id.$oid}}'
    name: 'repository_item'
```

---

```
#Service
window.App.service 'fileUpload', (RepositoryItem) ->
  this.files = {}

  this.remove = (field) =>
    itemToRemove = field.value
    if (itemToRemove)
      field.value.remove().then ->
        index = field.items.indexOf itemToRemove
        field.items.splice index, 1
        field.value = field.items[0]

  this.init = (task, field) =>
    # IT WORKS
    RepositoryItem.query({
      realm: task.variables.realm, criterion:{taskId: task.id, formType: field.id}
    }).then (fileItems) =>
      this.files[field.id] = fileItems

  this.upload = (task, field, element) =>
    for file in element.files
      reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = (event) =>

        # IT DOES NOT WORK
        new RepositoryItem({
          formType: field.id, taskId: task.id, content: event.target.result, name: file.name
        }).create().then (newItem) =>
          console.log 'newItem'
          console.log newItem
          this.rootScope.$apply =>
            this.files[field.id].push newItem

      reader.readAsBinaryString file
```

---

```
#View
<script type="text/ng-template" id="fileUpload">
<div class="field">
  <table class='attachments' ng-init="fileUpload.init(task, f)">
    <tr>
      <td> Attachments </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    {{ fileUpload.files }}
    <tr ng-repeat="file in fileUpload.files[f.id]">
      <td> {{file.name}} </td>
      <td> XXX </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="file" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileUpload.upload({{task}}, {{f}}, this)"/>
</div>
</script>
```

and inside the upload method I make an attempt to create new RepositoryItem. This method should send request to the server (as it does in init action) but it does not send any request. How can I fix that?

**upd1:**

I have tracked nested calls of rails-angular-resource. It calls $http(config) but no request is tracked in network console nor by my server.